# Should the new new keyword be used while quering records into a list

Tags: apex

```
List<Account> acc1 = new List<Account>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account]);
List<Account> acc2 = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];
```

So can anyone explain what is happening in the backend here in the above 2 statements. What will happen if use new keyword and what will happen if we directly assign query result to the list?
And also please let me know which statement should be used mostly?

Answer (score 2):

The first operation clones the results of the query. This is almost always useless, and will take extra CPU time. You should not use the first form of the query under any normal circumstances. I've heard of rare instances where this fixes some kind of bug, but I've never encountered this personally. Use the second form for all normal use cases.

Answer (score 1):

In Salesforce, you can use the **[SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm)** query language to retrieve data from the database and store it in a list variable. A list is a collection of elements that can be accessed by index.

In the first statement, you are using the **new** keyword to create a new instance of the **[List](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_list.htm)** class and pass the **query** result as a parameter to the **constructor**. This means that you are explicitly creating a list object and initializing it with the query result.

In the second statement, you are directly assigning the **query** result to the **list** variable. This means that you are implicitly creating a list object and initializing it with the query result.

Both statements are valid and will produce the same result in the **backend**. However, the second statement is more concise and preferred by most developers. The new keyword is not necessary when you are assigning a query result to a list variable, as Salesforce will **automatically** create a **list** object for you.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks a Lot for the detailed explanation.